# UIButtons wont change image

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I set a number of UIButtons in IB. When I try to set them in the code using

```
[A1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"t1A.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This does not set the image. Could it be that the button wont change if it is set in IB?

Thanks

Comment: What is the control state of the button when you're trying to set the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 [A1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"t1A.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: `setImage:` and `setBackgroundImage:` are two completely different methods. A `UIButton` has both an `image` property and a `backgroundImage` property. Additionally, if setting one doesn't work, setting the other won't either.

Comment: make sure the image t1A.png is included in your project resource

Comment: Solved it. Actually it just happened to be the iphone simulator. Since the update, it does some strange things. I relaunched it and did a target clean. :P

Answer (score 0):

Apple Docs:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Try this:

```
[YourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYZ.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```